# Better way to exclude duplicates without creating new table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a query that uses a subquery to detect if an item in a joined table has a duplicate record, and if so the data is not pulled into the parent query:

```
select
  (f.listing_datetime) as datetime,
  round(avg(f.listing_price), 0) as price,
  round(avg(f.listing_sqft), 0) as sqft,
  round(avg(f.listing_p_per_sqft), 2) as p_per_ft,
  f.listing_neighborhood, count(*) as points
from ( 
    select
      a.listing_datetime, a.listing_price, a.listing_sqft, a.listing_p_per_sqft,
      a.listing_neighborhood, i.listing_tokens, count(i.listing_tokens) as c
    from
      agg_cl_data as a
      left join incoming_cl_data_desc as i
        on a.listing_url = i.listing_url
    where a.listing_datetime between curdate() - interval 30 day and curdate()
    group by i.listing_tokens
    having c < 2
  ) as f
group by day(f.listing_datetime), f.listing_neighborhood
order by f.listing_datetime;
```

As you can see, by using a simple way to deal with dupes with the HAVING clause, I'm actually losing the original record that was stored because any aggregated record with great than 2 is thrown out. Is there a better way to do this so that I don't lose some of the data, WITHOUT creating a new table that would be queried against?

Comment: Your current subquery is invalid, because you are grouping by `listing_tokens` alone, but then go on to select many other columns.

Comment: the current query runs, and the intention is to group by tokens alone in the subquery. Maybe i'm misunderstanding your comment

Comment: In an aggregate query, SQL permits selecting only the grouping columns, if any, and (aggregate) functions of the groups.  You are selecting many other columns, both in the subquery and in the main query.  MySQL allows this as an extension, but the results depend on the order in which the rows of each group are retrieved.

Comment: Remove the `having` clause?  Sample data and desired results would *really* help.

Comment: When there are multiple results with the same `i.listing_tokens`, which one do you want the query to return?

Comment: ah, yes I see. Now that I'm looking not all the other columns are dependent on the aggregated column. Some are, others are not. Let me re-write. Thanks for the check.

Comment: Also, does table `agg_cl` have a unique key?  `listing_url`, maybe?

Comment: listing_url is unique, yes

Comment: wait, wouldn't this subquery work because if c < 2, then there is no ambiguity about the other column values. if c > 1 then it's ambiguous, but those values aren't selected anyway because of the having clause

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'distinct' instead if 'having' in subquery. You will get each url only once without loosing it, even if there were two entries for it.

So your code should be:

```
select DISTINCT a.listing_datetime, ...
```

and then no 'having' in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicate rows then use DISTINCT clause. If you want to find out duplicate based on partitioning on a particular column use the ROW_NUMBER window function.

On first glance, your subquery is invalid since you are grouping by one column and not using any other aggregate function in the other columns.

```
select distinct
  a.listing_datetime, a.listing_price, a.listing_sqft, a.listing_p_per_sqft,
  a.listing_neighborhood, i.listing_tokens
from
  agg_cl_data as a
  left join incoming_cl_data_desc as i
    on a.listing_url = i.listing_url
where a.listing_datetime between curdate() - interval 30 day and curdate()
```

Comment: The issue is that none of these columns is unique, but I want to determine a duplicate by the listing_tokens column, so distinct would not work, because distinct will compare across all those columns and you can only determine a duplicate from the listing_tokens column

Comment: also, wouldn't this subquery work because if c < 2, then there is no ambiguity about the other column values. if c > 1 then it's ambiguous, but those values aren't selected anyway because of the having clause?